# How do I generate a random number, put them into dictionary and then give back the count of repetitions

Tags: python, random

I have the task to create a function that is calculating a random number, which is then added into a dictionary until a this number is randomly generated again. As a result the number of repetitions has to be printed into the console.

I have already tried the following but I do not get results. I am a Python beginner so I also feel a bit lost.

```
import random
def repetition(a, b):
    d = dict()
    x = random.randint(a ,b)
    for i in d:
        if x in d.values:
            return len(dict)
        else:        
            dict.update(x)
```

In the last step the results should be formated as a tuple of the generated numbers and then last but not least the number of repetitions which might look like this:

```
repetition(2, 5255)
([1244, 2415, ... ], 122)
```

Comment: It's good practice to give your variables are more meaningfull name than single letters like `a`, `b`, `x` etc.

Comment: your phrasing "number of repetitions" seems to be at odds with what the code is doing. You want the code to stop as soon as you see a repetition? In that case, you're asking for the "number of steps until repetition" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random
def repetition(a, b):
   x = random.randint(a ,b)
   y = None
   values = [x]
   i = 0
   while x != y:
      y = random.randint(a,b)
      values.append(y)
      i += 1
return((values, i))
```

This should return what you expect, I did not use any dictionary though.

Answer (score 0):

This might help!

```
def repetition(a, b):
    d = {}
    while 1:
        x = random.randint(a, b)
        if x in d:
            return list(d.values()), len(d)
        d[x] = x
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the collections.Counter. What is does is return you amount of the number in the list. 
Here is an example of how i could work.

```
import collections

x = [10,10,20,10,20]
c = collections.Counter(x)
print(c[10])
```